# How to include external js inside vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to make a `slide image` in my app using jQuery Slide Image I get from internet. This source must include external **JS** and **CSS**.

I just want to use this external library only for certain components, so I just want to import it in only one particular component (`Home Component`).

My app uses `webpack` as a module bundler. How do I import external js file? I have tried doing it inside `<script>` in Vue Components like

```
var slide = require('assets/template/js/jssor.slider-26.1.5.min.js');
```

But I got error :

```
Error: Cannot find module "assets/template/js/jssor.slider-26.1.5.min.js"
```

My application structure
[image]

If the way I imported `js files` is **wrong**, how is the right way to use this js only on home component, without all components hit if i register in index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Module paths are resolved relative to the file being compiled. In this case, to import external script you need a path like:

```
var slide = require('../assets/template/js/jssor.slider-26.1.5.min.js');
```

Comment: Thanks @riyaz-ali for your improvement. Does this case also apply to `css` files?

Comment: Yes, and it applies to pretty much any resource webpack can load... checkout [how webpack resolves module paths](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/) here