# How to use an external module inside a Vue SFC?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, components, vue-component

I'm new to Vue, and I'm trying to build an app which uses Typescript and [`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator). This is my first attempt to use an external module inside an SFC. I want to create a calendar component using [`v-calendar`](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar) and render it in a page (`schedule.vue`).

I've done `yarn add`, and I'm trying to follow what the [docs](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar#2b-components-method) say about using v-calendar as a component. But as of now, when I try to render the page, there are no compilation errors yet the whole page goes blank. What's going wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
// pages/schedule.vue
<template lang="pug">
  VCalendar
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import VCalendar from '../components/calendar.vue';

@Component({
  components: {
    VCalendar
  }
})

export default class Schedule extends Vue {
}
```

```js
// components/calendar.vue
<template lang="pug">
  <v-calendar :attributes="attrs" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import 'v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.min.css';
import { Calendar, setupCalendar } from 'v-calendar';
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
  components: {
    setupCalendar,
    Calendar
  }
})

export default class VCalendar extends Vue {
  data() {
    return {
      attrs: [
        {
          key: 'today',
          highlight: {
            backgroundColor: '#ff8080',
          },
          dates: new Date(2018, 0, 1)
        }
      ],
    };
  }

  mounted():any {
    setupCalendar({
      firstDayOfWeek: 2,
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

I've checked these questions but I'm still lost:

- [How to use external vue npm components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48141191/11249670)
- [How to include external js inside vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46039148/11249670)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma How/where do I register it?

Comment: If you mean [registration](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) like `Vue.component(...)`, I was under the impression that I don't need this because I'm using [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Yes actually: `[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"` `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: You might be gettin this error because VCalendar is also the name of element in v-calendar library , try with changing the name of component for your SFC

Comment: You might be right - changed `VCalendar` in `schedule.vue` to `CalendarComponent`, and the error message changed. `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-calendar> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.` Does this mean the component is not "registered" as you mentioned earlier?

Comment: You need to remove the Calendar from Component annotation and add Vue.component(...)

Comment: I'm doubtful that's the case... Like I linked above, we're using [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) whose syntax is _not_ to use `Vue.component(...)`. Could you give a concrete example of the line you would add?

Comment: You need to register it globally using Vue.component('v-calendar',Calendar ) or if in case of class based SFC you are importing Calendar a named import, then it should be used as <calendar></calendar>. So either way it will work. SFC can use Components registered globally. @Component({
  components: {
    setupCalendar,
    'v-calendar':Calendar
  }
})can be done in class based SFCs.

Comment: You're right, I should've been using <calendar></calendar>. Now Vue seems to know what I was talking about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register it globally using `Vue.component('v-calendar',Calendar )` or in case of class based SFC you are importing Calendar a named import, then it should be used as `<calendar></calendar>`
`@Component({ components: { setupCalendar, 'v-calendar':Calendar } })` can also be used in class based SFCs to provide a custom tag name to some imported component.